# CSS make every letter in a text of a different colour

Tags: css, letters

Hi i have to make a text that have different colour for each letter.
I have tried to do this, it works. I want to know if there is a faster way to do this, using only CSS.

```
p {font-size: 36px;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   }
.blue{color: blue;}
.rosso{color:red;}
.grigio{color:grey;}
.oro{color:gold;}
.fucsia{color:fuchsia;}
.verde{color:green;}
.giallo{color: yellow;}
.rosa{color:pink;}
```

I use it in html:

```
<p><span class="blue">F</span><span class="rosso">i</span><span class="giallo">l</span><span       class="verde">o</span></p>
```

Comment: No. There's no way to define different colors for different letters for a single paragraph (without wrapping in span.)

Comment: No, you can't target a single letter, except for the first one (`::first-letter`).

Comment: in that link there is JavaScript..i can't use it.. i haven't already studied..

Answer (score 2):

You can use css nth child selector - `p:nth-child()` for doing it, specify your item number inside bracket(1,2,3 etc) as per your requirements and set color for it.

Comment: Why is `nth-child()` going to be helpful here?

Comment: you can do it more efficiently, no need to write class for every letter, just specify nth child's number and define your preferred color or any properties for it.

Comment: But I think the idea of the classes is that colours could be applied to any letter. Using this method, numbers would be assigned to elements by there index I.E. The first element would have to be red the second would have to be blue etc..

Comment: May be questioner can answer this question.

Comment: sorry, but i don't think that i can use nth-child.. i need to make every letter of a different color, with nth-child i select all the <p> not every letter. If you can..can you write an example?

Comment: You need to write p:nth-child(1){color:blue},p:nth-child(2){color:red} etc and you can define as much you need.

Comment: nth-child does not work for letters within a word.